# WPF DataGrid column with CheckBoxes not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have this very weird behavior with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` that holds a `CheckBox`.
The template holds a single checkbox currently not bound to anything for testing purposes.
[Here is a demonstration of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOCHx.jpg)
Here is the code:

```xml
<DataGrid Margin="0,78,0,0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Prikaz}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CanUserAddRows="False" 
            CanUserSortColumns="False"
            CanUserResizeColumns="False"
            HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#D6D6D6"
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="#D6D6D6"
            HeadersVisibility="Column">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="25">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The grid is bound to a `DataTable` so it generates rows.

**Problem:**
If I check a couple of `CheckBox` items in the grid and then scroll fast, the `CheckBox` items in the grid start randomly checking and unchecking. I have barely found anything on this issue so far. Is there an explanation to this weird behavior ?

Comment: Then bind them to something ... Prolly it's because of some kind of reusing/recycling of controls

Comment: They we bound to a column in the DataTable that controlled their checked state. Default value was 0 / unchecked for every row and the issue still persisted.

Comment: I think I found a solution to the issue. It seems that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the binding does the trick. I am not really sure why that works. Can anyone elaborate on this please ?

Answer (score 0):

The `CheckBox` elements in the item containers are reused for performance reasons by default. You can turn the virtualizing off by setting the `VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode` attached property to `Standard`:

```
<DataGrid ... VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
```

The other option is otherwise to use data binding to bind the `CheckBox` to a property of an object in memory that doesn't change when you scroll.